# How to set a class name for a div dynamically in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to set a class name for a div dynamically in react.js. I have five div with the same class name. I want to rotate a div which I am clicking. I tried to achieve through using state like:

```
handleClick(event) {
    this.setState({rotate: true})
}

handleFlip(event) {
    this.setState({rotate: false})
}

render() {
    return(
        <div className={rotate ? 'flip' : ''}></div>
    )
}
```

When I click the div, all divs with the same class name are rotating. But I want to rotate the div which I am clicking.

Comment: You should already have a reference to the source element that the click event originates? Have you looked at what properties exist on the `event`  object and handle the render function inside the function?

Answer (score 4):

You need to store the id of the div clicked instead of boolean as you need some way of determining which div was clicked. These id can be obtained from the event object or passed directly to the handleClick function whichever seems feasible to you. Also id can be anything that uniquely identifies the div.

you could do it like

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    rotated: ''
  }
  handleClick = (event)  => {
    const id = event.target.getAttribute('data-id');
    this.setState({ rotate: id })
  }

  render() {
    const {rotate} = this.state;
    return (
      <div style={styles} onClick={this.handleClick}>
        <div data-id="1" className={rotate === "1" ? 'flip' : ''}>Hello</div>
        <div data-id="2" className={rotate === "2" ? 'flip' : ''}>Hello</div>
        <div data-id="3" className={rotate === "3" ? 'flip' : ''}>Hello</div>
        <div data-id="4" className={rotate === "4" ? 'flip' : ''}>Hello</div>
        <div data-id="5" className={rotate === "5" ? 'flip' : ''}>Hello</div>
        <div data-id="6" className={rotate === "6" ? 'flip' : ''}>Hello</div>
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen {'\u2728'}</h2>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Problem is, you are controlling all the div by a single state bool, that's why all the divs are rotating at the same time.

**Solution:**

Instead of maintaining a single bool in state, store some unique identity of clicked div, and apply the class name if state value matches to div unique value.

Like this:

```
<div id='first' className={rotate=='first' ? 'flip' : ''}></div>
<div id='second' className={rotate=='second' ? 'flip' : ''}></div>
<div id='third' className={rotate=='third' ? 'flip' : ''}></div>
<div id='four' className={rotate=='four' ? 'flip' : ''}></div>
<div id='five' className={rotate=='five' ? 'flip' : ''}></div>
```

And inside onClick store that unique value in state:

```
handleClick(event) {
    this.setState({rotate: event.target.id})
}
```

**Update:**

Since you are generating the divs dynamically, you can assign the indexes, like this:

```
a=[1,2,3,4];
a.map((el, i) => <div id={i} key={i} className={rotate==i ? 'flip' : ''}></div>)
```

Comment: div are generated dynamically based on json data.

Comment: you can assign anything, like indexes (it will be unique), and check the 0,1,2 value before applying the class.

Comment: @Kallis check the update section, how to apply indexes :)

Comment: Sure, i ll check.. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Solution demo - https://codesandbox.io/s/73znpxwn2j

React Component File -

```
import React from 'react';

class Hello extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state ={
      rotate: true
    }
  }
  handleClick(event) {
    this.setState({ rotate: true })
  }

  handleFlip(event) {
    this.setState({ rotate: false })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className={this.state.rotate ? 'flip' : ''}>Hello
      </div>
    )
  }
}

render(<Hello />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Html File -

```
  <style>
.flip{
  color:red;
}
</style>
```

Comment: The demo doesn't work, and the code does not address the problem of having *many* `div`s.

Comment: Hey, did you tried changing state, then see if code works. Because I tested before posting here.

Comment: It is meant to work with `handleClick` and `handleFip`.  Otherwise, you are only testing React.  Plus, the issue is about rendering multiple `div`s dynamically and only flipping one at a time.

Comment: They will obviously not work as I did not handled events or methods, because I did to check skeleton see if the className is accepting the name